# I am working on ASP.NET MVC applicaion, I need implement auto log off feature after 10 min

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I start, for auto log off feature after 10 mins, for ASP.NET MVC web application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   this helps you to ask query Better

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your web.config file.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
   <sessionState timeout="10"></sessionState>
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And if you want to redirect user to specific URL, then you need Authorization.